# JFreeChart: how to change XYPlot foreground color?

Tags: java, jfreechart

The JFreeChart XYPlot background color is changed using `setBackgroundPaint()` but there doesn't seem to be a corresponding `setForegroundPaint()`.

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.BLACK);
```

How is the foreground color (the plot) changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

eg:

```
XYItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.CYAN);
```