# Changing background colour of jFreeChart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I am trying to change the background color of jfreechart. 
It is displaying in grey color and I want a white background. 
I have tried

```
chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
```

However it does not show me the white background.
I have the following code that displays the the plot

```
chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Line Chart","Year","Temperature", dataset);
ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart, false);
graph1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
graph1.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
graph1.add(chartPanel);
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
graph1.updateUI();
System.out.println("Database created successfully...");
```

How should I set a white background?

Comment: chartPanel is added twice to graph1

Comment: Don't call updateComponentTree or. UpdateUI, these are expensive calls and are related to updating the look and feel

Comment: Please edit your question to include version numbers, an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and a [screenshot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) that shows the expected result.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

ChartPanel inherit method [javax.swing.JComponent.setBackground(java.awt.Color)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground(java.awt.Color))

```
chartPanel.setBackground( Color.RED );
```

Or try:

```
chart.getPlot().setBackgroundPaint( Color.BLUE );
```

See documentation of [JFreeChart.getPlot()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html#getPlot--) and [Plot.setBackgroundPaint()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/Plot.html#setBackgroundPaint-java.awt.Paint-)

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421154/jfreechart-setbackgroundpaint-not-doing-anything) on SO or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052083/jfreechart-how-to-change-xyplot-foreground-color) too.

Comment: The first example doesn't work on my side, the second one does.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `JFreeChart.getPlot().setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset(); 
    pieDataset.setValue("LoggedIn" +": "+ 5, 10);
    pieDataset.setValue("LoggedOut" +": "+ 8, 17);
    JFreeChart jfc = ChartFactory.createPieChart("title", pieDataset, false, false, false );
    jfc.getPlot().setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
    ChartPanel chart = new ChartPanel(jfc);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(chart);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I hope it helps!